# How to add two activties/screens data at one time in same Document IDs in firebase firestore android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Android and working on a project where I need to get the input from users through multiple activities and then add that data to the Firebase Firestore but the problem I m facing is that the data is saved in different documents IDs but I want it to be in the same document id?? So that I can retrieve the data at once. Please guide me on how can I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share some code that you tried.

Comment: As per the @Rohit Jakhar shared answer, can you check with these links: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531507/best-practice-mvvm-pass-data-from-one-activity-to-another and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Fragment for showing UI and use SharedViewModel for saving data at one place.
2. Using activity, pass data from one activity to another and merge and pass to another until last activtity.
3. Create table for complete data and access and update it in every activity and at last, get table data and upload to firestore.

These are the few generic approach for sharing data in activities and fragments.

Comment: thank you rohit bhai for your guidance. as  i am new to android so I partially understand what you have suggested me, can you refer me to any documents or videos to achieve this whole thing??

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling [CollectionReference#add(Object data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#add(java.lang.Object)) or [DocumentReference#document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) without passing any ID, it will always assign a unique document ID automatically. If you do one of these operations in different activities, then you'll end up always having **different** document IDs.

If you need to write data to the same document from different activities, you either save the data under a **fixed** (known) document ID, or you pass the first generated ID from one activity to another, as I also mentioned in one earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065849/how-to-add-multiple-activities-data-to-firebase-firestore-under-same-document-id) of yours.

Comment: Hey Vivek. Can I help you with other information?